# How to replace a specific line of HTML code with Regular Expression In Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver, replace

I want to replace `<whatever>Some Title</whatever>` with `<something>Some Title</something>` using the Find and Replace tool inside of Dreamweaver. How do I perform?

Answer (score 0):

Not a Dreamweaver user, but this simple approach works in my editor (Emacs):

Replace:

```
<whatever>\(.*\)</whatever>
```

With:

```
<something>\1</something>
```

This is a pretty straightforward approach but it may fall short of your needs. Do some or all of your `<whatever>` element pairs occupy more than one line of text? Or do you have more than one `<whatever>` pair on a single line?

Answer (score 0):

i guess what you want is to change all your `<whatever>` tag with an `<something>` tag whitout changing  your text, right?

If it is so, you want to use *find and replace* with regular expression. Find (in source code) `<whatever>(.*)</whatever>` and replace it with `<something>$1</something>`. The `$1` is used as a variable for anything fits the `(.*)` part DW finds for each instance.

For example, you you want to comment all instances of an
`document.NAMEOFANYFORMONTHEPAGE.WHATEVERNAME.focus();` 
in a JavaScript file, you would use find: 
`document\.(.*)\.focus\(\);` 
and replace it with: 
`// document.$1.focus();`

Don't forget to escape special characters and, please, try a few instances before using *Replace All*